# How to use create-react-app build with custom enviroment variables?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have some custom enviroment variables for example:
`REACT_APP_API_URL='http://localhost:6000/api'`

... and different enviroments (`develop`, `test`, `uat` and `production`).

How can I define custom **variables** and custom **build command** for each enviroment?

I found [this CRA documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) but it works with Node variables.

Comment: This question is not very clear. What is wrong with the example that you have provided? That should work just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could install [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and use that to set custom `REACT_APP_*` environment variables for your scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "develop": "cross-env REACT_APP_TEST=start react-scripts start",
  "test": "cross-env REACT_APP_TEST=test react-scripts start",
  "uat": "cross-env REACT_APP_TEST=uat react-scripts start",
  "production": "cross-env REACT_APP_TEST=production react-scripts build",
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I have many enviroment variables? Is it alright to put all of then into the command?

Comment: @froston No problem! Yes, if you have multiple environment variables you can just list them after each other. That is the best option in my opinion, if you don't have that many of them.

Comment: I found a related project [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd)  which allows having these variables in `.env.develop`, `.env.uat` ... files.